# UIDynamicAnimator for views with CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do you make UIDynamicAnimator to play along with a view that has a CGAffineTransform on it?

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

When running a UIDynamicAnimator, the scale is set back to normal state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you add the object to an animator after the size is set it should be fine. Dynamic animator reads the transform once and then only writes it after that. If you change the size afterwards, you should remove the object from behaviors, change the size and re-add it back. Or you can just add your object into a UIView and add that to animator, then you can change size of your object whenever you want and the animator won't care.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change this transform after you've already added the `UIDynamicAnimator`, you'll want to use [**`updateItemUsingCurrentState:`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDynamicAnimator/updateItemUsingCurrentState%3a) to inform the animator that it needs to update the current animation based on the new state.