# CGAffineTransformScale does not send it's scale when using UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am simply trying to understand the way to use updateItemUsingCurrentState and how to send a scaled UIView or UIImageView to the animator so I can have a large box and small box for physics tests on viewDidLoad. I want to learn how to pass it this info so I can dynamically change the size later in other events.

I saw the updateItemUsingCurrentState is the answer from the link below and apples docs but no hard example to get a scale to work.
[UIDynamicAnimator for views with CGAffineTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037729/uidynamicanimator-for-views-with-cgaffinetransform)

Im sure ill find out that I need to change the bounds or something else later, but for now I just wanna get past this barrier.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *CatBox;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *catFishBox;
@property (nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator* animator;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *wrapperWolfBox;

@end

@implementation CatFishViewController

UIDynamicAnimator* _animator;
UIGravityBehavior* _gravity;
UICollisionBehavior* _collision;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    _gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[_wrapperWolfBox]];
    [_animator addBehavior:_gravity];

    _collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc]
                  initWithItems:@[_wrapperWolfBox]];
    _collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    [_animator addBehavior:_collision];
//
// 

    CGAffineTransform maybeGetTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_wrapperWolfBox.transform, 2.2, 2.2);
    _wrapperWolfBox.transform = maybeGetTransform;


    [_animator updateItemUsingCurrentState:self.wrapperWolfBox];




//    _animator.updateItemUsingCurrentState:self.catFishBox;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im here to answer my own Q as the internet seems to not seem to ask, so i missed some doc somewhere.

You can't use Affines They just don't play nice with animator.
So I found that you remove the view from the dynamics and change the "bounds" or "frame" then add the view back to the animator.

```
[_gravity removeItem:_wrapperWolfBox];
  CGRect frameZr = _wrapperWolfBox.bounds;
    frameZr.size.height += 60.0f;
    frameZr.size.width += 60.0f;
    _wrapperWolfBox.bounds = frameZr;
[_gravity addItem:_wrapperWolfBox];
```

Which brings me to my next new fun question and finding. Scale is instant. Of which you might want but I don't. So ill ask that in a new post.

Enjoy!