# Trying to mix UIKit Dynamics UICollision and core animation to scale a box's bounds

Tags: uikit, core-animation

From a previous question I had.
[CGAffineTransformScale does not send it's scale when using UIDynamicAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869111/cgaffinetransformscale-does-not-send-its-scale-when-using-uidynamicanimator/20262476#20262476)

Im trying to mix an animated scale effect on a box that has a smaller box on top of it.
Both boxes have UICollisionBehavior, I want to eventually make the bottom box thats getting larger scale fast enough to provide a velocity force I that will make the top box react with a bounce up.

The below is the scale code. The bounds is instantly set to its target final while the image in the view is still scaling. I want the bounds and image to be scaling at the same time so I can see the expected reactions happening.

```
- (IBAction)tapBoxThing:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {


    /* Make sure no translation is applied to this image view */
    _boxView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    /* Begin the animation */
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil
                    context:NULL];

    /* Make the animation 5 seconds long */
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0f];

    [_gravity removeItem:_boxView];
    [_collision removeItem:_boxView];


    // right here, the box will animate the image in the view to slowly fill in the new bounds.
    // But I want the bounds to animate, its currently instantly scaling to teh final ammount.
    // Core Animation states that frame is not animatable but bounds is.

    CGRect frameZ = _boxView.bounds;
    frameZ.size.height += 60.0f;
    frameZ.size.width += 60.0f;
    _boxView.bounds = frameZ;



   [_gravity addItem:_boxView];
   [_collision addItem:_boxView];


    [UIView commitAnimations];



}
```